# What code must be run in onCreate() before finish() can be called?

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate, activity-finish

I want to do a test for a condition in an Activity's `onCreate()` which if true will call `finish()`. Is there any code which must be called before finish() is called? (And must any code be run after finish() is called?)

e.g.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // I'm pretty sure this is always required
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // is this required?
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can freely call `finish()` in onCreate without calling some extra methods, for example:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //REQUIRED

    if (isVariable) {
     finish();
    } else {
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     //code here
    }
}
```

And when you call finish It will not stop executing method, so make sure nothing is below `finish()` line.

And you should not call `setContentView` If you will call finish in onCreate to save memory/speed.

I have tested this approach and it works fine.